# How to get last record of mysql group by method on my sql

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I want to get the last record (max created date) from the SQL method group by with inner join that I made

I have tried several ways, one of them uses 2 select methods, and it's not working

===========Table===========

**Table Data**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzevG.png

**Table Object**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW9dK.png

**Table Variable**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaJMp.png

**Table Block**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoC6k.png

Here's the SQL that I use

```
SELECT b.name, dt.objectCode, dt.objectAlias,
        MAX(dt.created_at),
        IF(dt.variableId= '54' , dt.textValue, NULL ) AS Panen,
        IF(dt.variableId= '45' , dt.textValue, NULL ) AS BuahBesar,
        IF(dt.variableId= '44' , dt.textValue, NULL ) AS Pentil,
        IF(dt.variableId= '42' , dt.textValue, NULL ) AS KuncupBunga    
FROM data AS dt
INNER JOIN object AS ob
        ON dt.objectAlias = ob.objectAlias
INNER JOIN block AS b
        ON b.id = ob.blockId
AND dt.textValue = 'Ya' OR dt.textValue = 'Sudah' WHERE b.name = "A1"
GROUP BY dt.objectAlias
```

and the result is

**Unwanted Result**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqDlJ.png

the expected result based on last MAX "created_at" on tbl_data is "2019-03-05 11:09:59" where "YA" is on the KuncupBunga

**Expected Result**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tuIF.png

Comment: Your query is invalid, because you select columns which do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: sorry, I have tried it and it shows results, but it is not according to my expectations
https://i.imgur.com/ZmaKt3g.png?2